# Secure Robotic Mesh Ad-Hoc Networking with Linux

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, ad-hoc-network

For a research project, i need to create a mesh network to my robots.

I found some long range usb wifi adapters (Alfa AWUS036NHRv2) and hook up to my raspberyy pi 3b+ (i have 4 adapters and 4 rpi3).

I need to create some kind of mesh networking with these adapters and rpi3s to my robots.

I found that the ad-hoc networking creates routerless wireless networks.

Tried between two of my rpi3's with adapters and they works OK.

But there is no encryption.

I need to set some password to my network and also try to figure out some mesh structure (for example all robot know each others data).

What path should i follow?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using 802.11s instead of ad-hoc. 802.11s supports encryption (installing some additional packages).

Have a look at [this page](https://mjuenema.github.io/80211s_wireless_mesh/) where you can find instructions for Raspbian, otherwise you can do that easily with [OpenWrt and 802.11s](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/mesh/80211s) (or even with [LibreMesh](https://libremesh.org/), which is based on OpenWrt but has 802.11s pre-configured).

For sharing files between all the Raspberry Pi you can try with [alfred](https://www.open-mesh.org/projects/alfred/wiki) (even if it's from BATMAN-adv people, alfred does not need BATMAN-adv in order to do its work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I currently have many raspberry pi's and also some usb wifi adapters called ALFA AWUS036NHRV2. They have RTL8188RU chips. Can i configure them to work with 802.11s? If not, how can i decide that a usb wifi adapter that has some rf chip compatible with 802.11s?

Comment: That's a good question... That chip was supported by `rtl8192cu` module that was replaced by `rtl8xxxu`. [Here](https://github.com/phillymesh/802.11s-adapters/blob/master/README.md) they say that when using `rt2800usb` driver it should support 802.11s. The source of `rtl8xxxu` is [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu) and the source of `rt2800usb` is [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00) and I can not understand if 802.11s is supported, sorry :/

Comment: hello again and sorry for the delay. I tried the wifi adapters but get the "The operation not supported (-95) " error on the raspberry pi's. I tried the first link you send to me. The adapters works perfectly with 2 of my computers installed debian on them but raspberry pi's not working. I'll buy one of the AWUS036NH to try. If i see no error i will buy more of them. Also i didn't understand how can i secure my mesh :(

Comment: Which is the command that triggers the "The operation not supported (-95)" (never saw it) error? Do them work for more basic operations like scanning or neither that? Anyway, for securing the network the "Security" section in the first link should do https://mjuenema.github.io/80211s_wireless_mesh/#security (but I never tried) on OpenWrt also works, check out the linked page.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers sir. https://mjuenema.github.io/80211s_wireless_mesh/#creating-a-wireless-mesh-network in this link, when i try to execute "sudo iw dev wlan1 interface add mesh0 type mp mesh_id MYMESHID" i get that error immediately. wlan1 is the connected alfa wifi adapter (AWUS036NHRv2 which uses RTL8188RU chip). I have two laptops in my lab which runs the latest debian linux and the adapters works perfectly on mesh mode in them. i get about 24Mbps.

Comment: Please try doing a simple scan, if it also fails means that the driver is just missing or not loaded. The command for a scan should be `iw dev wlan1 scan` where wlan1 could also be wlan0

Comment: thanks for all of your answers. i get one of the alfa awus036nh modems which has ralink 3070 chip. It is working with open-mesh's batman. it is really nice implementation and very stable. but periodically i get some low bandwidth in my setup. two adapters located at 3m distance to each other. most of the time i get 2.5MBps but sometimes it lowers down to 200kBps. stays at this rate for about 30 to 45 secs than get up to again 2.5MBps level.